# Bash - Sed / Awk replacing string with new line

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file with strings like this below and want replace everthing between the "steps:" and "-" with a new line:

```
- name: Change It uid: Change It_TRANS_App - Web type: TRANSACTION steps: 02 - name: Change It 1 type: BSTEP uid: Step 1_STEP_Change It_TRANS_App -strong text Web rules:
```

I've tried using awk like:

```
echo $string | awk {'gsub(/steps:.*?-/ , 'steps:\n-' )'; print $0}
```

However, I get the error below:

```
awk: {gsub(/steps:.*?-/ , steps:n- )
awk:                          ^ syntax error
awk: fatal: 0 is invalid as number of arguments for gsub
```

I've tried as well with sed:

```
sed -r 's:/\bsteps:\b.*?-/\n/' stringfile.txt > output.txt
```

and removing the ":":

```
sed -r 's/\bsteps.*?-/\n/' stringfile.txt > output.txt
```

In the first case, I get the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unterminated `s' command
```

And with the second sed I removes a lot of other things that it shouldn't.

[Edit] As you guys told me, I forgot to put the expected output, I've been thinking that it would be simple, however I'm not good. I've want to "break" as a new line cuting out just the word right after "step", in that case, would be "02".
It would be to the first occurence of "-":

```
- name: Change It uid: Change It_TRANS_App - Web type: TRANSACTION steps:
- name: Change It 1 type: BSTEP uid: Step 1_STEP_Change It_TRANS_App -strong text Web rules:
```

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins as you do not yet know the basics of awk and that book will help you get started AND is a good reference for more complicated problems.

Comment: echoing comment below, please edit your question to include your required/expected output. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sed won't support non-greedy patterns `*?`, you could use a negated class character class.

```
sed -r 's/\bsteps[^-]*-/\n-/' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed -r 's/\bsteps[^-]*/\n/' file
- name: Change It uid: Change It_TRANS_App - Web type: TRANSACTION 
- name: Change It 1 type: BSTEP uid: Step 1_STEP_Change It_TRANS_App -strong text Web rules:
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
awk '{gsub(/steps:.*-/,"steps:\n-");print $0}' <<< "$sting"
- name: Change It uid: Change It_TRANS_App - Web type: TRANSACTION steps:
-strong text Web rules:
```

---

Can be shorted to:

```
awk '{gsub(/steps:.*-/,"steps:\n-")}1' <<< "$sting"
```

---

Ref Eds comments:

```
awk '{gsub(/steps:[^-]*-/,"steps:\n-")}1' t
- name: Change It uid: Change It_TRANS_App - Web type: TRANSACTION steps:
- name: Change It 1 type: BSTEP uid: Step 1_STEP_Change It_TRANS_App -strong text Web rules:
```

Comment: Since the OP in his question seems to be trying to use a non-greedy operator, I suspect what he really needs for the RE is `/steps:[^-]*-/`. Without him posting expected output we're all just guessing though.

Answer (score 0):

While `awk` and `sed` gurus are providing the solution, may I suggest to consider using Perl.

To substitute for the new line everything until the first occurrence of `-`in the string:

```
echo $string | perl -pe 's/(.*steps:).*?(-.*)/$1\n$2/'
- name: Change It uid: Change It_TRANS_App - Web type: TRANSACTION steps:
- name: Change It 1 type: BSTEP uid: Step 1_STEP_Change It_TRANS_App -strong text Web rules:
```

To substitute for the new line everything until the last occurrence of `-`in the string:

```
echo $string | perl -pe 's/(.*steps:).*(-.*)/$1\n$2/'
- name: Change It uid: Change It_TRANS_App - Web type: TRANSACTION steps:
-strong text Web rules:
```

Two expressions inside parenthesis are refereed to as $1 and $2 in the second half of the substitution expression. And then `?` in the middle part regulates whether `.*` works greedy or not greedy.